# iOS13 apns-push-type header on azure notification hub

Tags: ios, azure, push-notification, ios13, azure-notificationhub

Starting from iOS 13 and watchOS 6 Apple requires the presence of the header `apns-push-type` (the value of this header can be `alert` or `background`) for push notification.

According to Apple documentation:

> The value of this header must accurately reflect the contents of your notification's payload. If there is a mismatch, or if the header is missing on required systems, APNs may delay the delivery of the notification or drop it altogether.

```
    HEADERS
      - END_STREAM
      + END_HEADERS
      :method = POST
      :scheme = https
      :path = /3/device/xxxxxx
      host = api.sandbox.push.apple.com
      authorization = bearer xxx
      apns-id = xxx-xxx-xxx
      apns-push-type = alert
      apns-expiration = 0
      apns-priority = 10
      apns-topic = com.example.MyApp
    DATA
      + END_STREAM
      { "aps" : { "alert" : "Hello" } }
```

[see Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns)

Unfortunately using azure notification hub I can only define `aps`content but not the header.

```
{ "aps": { "alert":"Alert message!", "content-available": 1 }, "CustomData": "$(CustomData)" }
```

How is it handled by azure notification hub?
How can I specify the type of the notification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some experiments and a little bit of investigation, this is the current Azure server behavior...

The server inspects the contents of the notification to infer the correct value.

If "content-available": 1 is present and "alert" is missing then the `"apns-push-type" = "background"` is added to the header.

If a valid "alert" is present then the `"apns-push-type" = "alert"` is added to the header.

So take care of having a valid APNS JSON body, with correctly populated content-available/alert properties.

See this [discussion thread](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-dotnet/issues/88)  for more info

UPDATE 2019-10-15:
Currently there are some problems with background silent notification
See the following discussion:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-dotnet/issues/96

UPDATE 2019-11-25:
The server was rejecting installations against APNS that included headers. Now this issue is fixed and the silent notification should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not accurate, background push is not working on azure right now. The headers need to be included during sending a push as shown below and also the hub needs to be configured with a key and not a certificate:

```
var backgroundHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "apns-push-type", "background" }, { "apns-priority", "5" } };
 Dictionary<string, string> templateParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
// populated templateParams 

 var notification = new TemplateNotification(templateParams);
 notification.Headers = backgroundHeaders;
// the second parameter is the tag name and the template name as we have it registered from the device.
 var resBack = await hubClient.SendNotificationAsync(notification, tags);
```